# Insert data in postgresql table django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Here is how my **views.py** looks like

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])

def AnswersList(request):


if request.method == 'GET': # user requesting data 
    snippets = PAResponse.objects.all()
    serializer = PAAnswersSerializer(snippets, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

elif request.method == 'POST': # user posting data
    serializer = PAAnswersSerializer(data=request.data)
    #print("serializer in post",type(serializer),serializer)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save() # save to db
        result=Calculate(serializer)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

in post method  i am sending my serializer as an argument to the "Calculate" function which is written in calculations.py . Calculate function returns me a list . but i am struggling on how can i send the element of list in different model from calculations.py list looks like this
**Result_list= [1,20,14,14,38,8,82]**     which i want to send in AnalysisResult class of model.

My **models.py**

```
class AnalysisResult(models.Model):
user_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
E=models.IntegerField()
A=models.IntegerField()
C=models.IntegerField()
N=models.IntegerField()
O=models.IntegerField()
total=models.IntegerField()
class Meta:
    db_table='analysis_result'
    
def __str__(self):
    return self.response
```

Please let me know if you need any more information. i am new to this so please help me .

In simple terms can i send **"Result_list"** to **db_table='analysis_result'** directly from calculations.py instead of views or models.py if not then how can i send data .
Any kind of lead will be helpful

***DB=postgressql 13***

I tried this in calculations.py

```
def Calculate(*args)
    ""some calucaltion""
    Result_lst.append(Total)
print("Result_lst",Result_lst)
for key,value in Ansdict.items():
    if key == 2:
        print("Question number",key)
        cursor = connections['postgres'].cursor()
        for d in Result_lst:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO analysis_result(user_id,E,A,C,N,O,total) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",d)


return Result_lst
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to save the data via serializer.

In your case

```
...

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save() # save to db
    result_list = Calculate(serializer) # result_list = [1, 20, 14, 14, 38, 8, 82]

    analysis_serializer = AnalysisResultSerializer(data={
       'user_id': result_list[0],
       'E': result_list[1],
       'A': result_list[2],
       'C': result_list[3],
       'N': result_list[4],
       'O': result_list[5],
       'total': result_list[6],
    })
    analysis_serializer.is_valid()
    analysis_serializer.save()

    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
...
```